# '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' error

Tags: python, pandas

```
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] <= 120) & (hd['ap_lo'] < 80), ['ap_hi','ap_lo']] = 'normal'
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] > 120) & (hd['ap_hi'] <= 129) & (hd['ap_lo'] < 80), ['ap_hi','ap_lo']] = 'elevated'
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] > 130) & (hd['ap_hi'] <= 139) | (hd['ap_lo'] >= 80) & (hd['ap_lo'] < 89), ['ap_hi','ap_lo']] = 'high blood pressure 1'
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] > 140) & (hd['ap_hi'] <= 179) | (hd['ap_lo'] > 90) & (hd['ap_lo'] <119 ), ['ap_hi','ap_lo']] = 'high blood pressure 2'
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] > 180) | (hd['ap_lo'] > 120) , ['ap_hi','ap_lo']] = 'hypertensive crisis'
```

When I run this code, I get the error `'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` on the second line. I don't know what caused the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us how you defined hd?

Comment: The error message looks clear to me. Type this in your interpreter: 'one' < 1

Comment: hd = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/sec/cardio_train.csv", sep = ";") and variables ap_hi and ap_lo are int.

Comment: On the first line of this code, you set some values of 'ap_hi' and 'ap_lo' to the string 'normal'. On the next line you compare those columns with 120 and you are comparing strings to integers. I would recommend that you create a new column to hold the words rather than changing the columns that already have the data.

Comment: Oh that makes sense thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting string values in columns that contain integers. Instead of doing this, create new columns for the strings. Here I'm creating a new column 'bp_level':

```
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] <= 120) & (hd['ap_lo'] < 80), 'bp_level'] = 'normal'
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] > 120) & (hd['ap_hi'] <= 129) & (hd['ap_lo'] < 80), 'bp_level'] = 'elevated'
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] > 130) & (hd['ap_hi'] <= 139) | (hd['ap_lo'] >= 80) & (hd['ap_lo'] < 89), 'bp_level'] = 'high blood pressure 1'
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] > 140) & (hd['ap_hi'] <= 179) | (hd['ap_lo'] > 90) & (hd['ap_lo'] <119 ), 'bp_level'] = 'high blood pressure 2'
hd.loc[(hd['ap_hi'] > 180) | (hd['ap_lo'] > 120) , 'bp_level'] = 'hypertensive crisis'
```

If you want to overwrite those columns, do it after you have finished all of the comparisons:

```
hd.loc[:,['ap_hi', 'ap_lo']] = hd['bp_level']
```

Here's a simpler, working example (tested with Python 3.8 and pandas 1.0.5):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10)})
df.loc[(df['A'] < 3), 'B'] = '<3'
df.loc[(df['A'] < 6) & (df['A'] >= 3), 'B'] = '3 to <6'
df.loc[(df['A'] >= 6), 'B'] = '6+'

print(df)
```

Produces:

```
   A        B
0  0       <3
1  1       <3
2  2       <3
3  3  3 to <6
4  4  3 to <6
5  5  3 to <6
6  6       6+
7  7       6+
8  8       6+
9  9       6+
```

Comment: This seems right but when I run it I got an error on the first line saying that "None of [Index(['bp_level'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]". Should I add something else?

Comment: Your problem was because I had left the 'bp_value' column name in a list when I removed 'ap_hi' and 'ap_lo'. Remove the brackets and it works fine. I've edited the code and added an example that shows it working correctly.